# Why no dependence on the phase in Wikipedia about Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series

I was reading the Wikipedia article about Fourier series to try to understand this concept. While reading about the [Fourier series decomposition of a real function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Exponential_form) the different phases $\phi_n$ appear in the formula for $c_n$.

But why in the section [Complex-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Complex-valued_functions) the phase $\phi_n$ doesn't appear anywhere anymore?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Use_of_complex_sinusoids_to_represent_real_sinusoids basically the coefficients in a phasor form are complex which encodes both amplitude and phase.

Comment: I think I understand. So acturally $c_n=a_n+i b_n$ and $c_n$ has module $A_n$ and argument $\phi_n$?